# something wrong when I install Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK

Tags: ios, swift, google-mobile-ads

when I try to add google mobile ads sdk to my file, there comes out some problems.

when i start install:

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9yzj.png)

there is nothing wrong here, but when i run the app with xcode, i got a lot of error:

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75zab.png)

i don't know how to fix that ...... if anyone could help me ? thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your old project(without Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK framework), I think it was working(compiling & running) properly. Now add Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK pod line in the project's pod file and install pod by **--no-repo-update** in the terminal.

```
pod install --no-repo-update
```